# How to fix: gradient background at landscaping?

Tags: swift, view, background, gradient

I have this code which creates a gradient background.
When I  rotate the deviace to landscape mode, the gradient background doesnt fill up to the whole size of the screen, some parts are white.

My goal is the whenever the orrientation changes, the gradient should fill the whole screen.

```
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let color1 =  UIColor(red: 198.0/255.0 , green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 221.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let color2 = UIColor(red: 251.0/255.0, green: 215.0/255.0, blue: 134.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let color3 =  UIColor(red: 247.0/255.0, green: 121.0/255.0, blue: 125.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    gradient.name="asd"
    gradient.colors = [color1,color2,color3]
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: wid, height: heu)

    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

Comment: try to readd gradient on layoutSubviews, or change it's frame

Comment: gradient.frame = bounds  // relative to parent views

Answer (score 1):

Hold the gradient layer as a property and update its frame in layoutSubview()

```
var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ///
    /// YOUR CODE
    ///
    gradientLayer = gradient
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```